# How do I make ANTLR double regex?

Tags: regex, antlr

I'm getting token recognition errors and I can't  figure out why.

```
DOUBLE: ^[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*$;
INT: [0-9]* ;
```

The `^`, `\` and `$` have red squiggly lines under them in the editor

[image: screenshot].

Comment: You might need to remove `^` and `$`

Comment: Have you written those regexes yourself or did you copy them from somewhere? Why did you decide to anchor the `DOUBLE` regex, but not `INT`?

Comment: Yeah, removing the ^ and $ anchors is fine, but it still doesn't like my escaped '.', which I don't know how to get around.

Comment: You should be able to substitue `[.]` for `\.` -- see if it likes that better.

Answer (score 1):

ANTLR doesn't use regular expressions for rule specifications. It might look like that sometimes, but it isn't. Your rule must be so instead:

```
DOUBLE: [0-9]+ '.'? [0-9]*;
```